# setting the absolute path for pages

Tags: php, html, apache, path

I have been working on my site structure trying to make it less cluttered but I am running into issues with file paths.

**site structure before**

```
[folder] :   css
[folder] :   js
[folder] :   images
[folder] :   include
   |---> :   header.php
[file]   :   index.php
[file]   :   view_inventory.php
....
```

**site structure after**

```
[folder] :   css
[folder] :   js
[folder] :   images
[folder] :   include
   |---> :   header.php
[folder] :   view
   |---> :   inventory.php
[file]   :   index.php
....
```

As you can see I have decided to group view files placing them into their own folder

The issue with this is that both **index.php** and **view_inventory.php** use the **include/header.php** file

The **include/header.php** file has a header logo located at **images/logo.php**, the path of the images would not be problem if both **index.php** and **view_inventory.php** were in the same folder, but since they aren't the file in **view/inventory.php** will have the incorrect image path.

I have thought about defining full paths for files such as images (e.g. localhost/sites/bk/images/logo.png) but it would be a bad idea because I may decide to upload the files onto a server and the server address can constantly change..etc

What is the best way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use absolute paths!

In your index.php do:

```
define( 'ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) );
```

And when you want to include the header file,

```
include ROOT . '/include/header.php'
```

And, when in html and want to use a image, use a absolute path from webroot:

```
<img src="/images/your_image.png">
```

Comment: the webroot does not work like that, it goes to `localhost/images/logo.png` when I need the file is located at `localhost/sites/bk/images/logo.png`

Comment: if http://localhost/images/logo.png displays the logo in the browser, then write your code as <img src="/images/your_image.png"> !

Comment: it's ok im changing the root path from htdocs to htdocs/sites/bk/